# How do I simplify the sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any way to say the following more elegantly:

> The argument relies on an unsupported, but likely correct, claim?

The intention is to say that some argument relies on a claim without providing an evidence. However, it is not a big problem, because the claim is likely correct. Can we say it in one line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses might be better:

> The argument relies on an unsupported (but likely correct), claim.

or "but" could be changed to "if", "albeit", or some other word.

Inverting the order might not be:

> While likely correct, the claim on which this argument is based is
>   unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

> This argument is predicated on a reasonable hypothesis.

A *[hypo](https://www.bing.com/search?q=hypothesis%20etymology&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=hypothesis%20etymology&sc=2-19&sk=&cvid=2EE2E3285BA544B395AD0C8A1455DB56)*-thesis would mean that the claim is unsubstantiated, however it is a reasonable one to hold.

Comment: This is good—except for the use of *predicated* which isn't a simple word. I would suggest using *based on* instead.

Comment: I think this is good, assuming she doesn't want to draw too much attention to the lack of evidence.

Answer (score 0):

It think it depends on what you wish to emphasise.

If the fact that the claim is unsupported is of primary importance, then I think Steve Smith's second answer is good.

If you want a slightly stronger emphasis on the fact that the claim is correct you could try:

'The argument relies on a claim which is unsupported but probably correct'.